# Можно ли откладывать углы в градусах на оси координат?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Можно ли в Python (Matplotlib) по оси абсцисс откладывать, допустим, обычные числа, а по оси ординат -- углы в градусах?

Comment: Если график в декартовой системе координат, то никакой разницы что откладывать по оси ординат нет.

Comment: А что вам может помешать?

Comment: Считал, что нужно производить какой-то перерасчет. Но раз не нужно, тем и лучше. Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib позволяет строить несколько типов графиков. Похоже, что в вашем вопросе речь идет о графике в двумерной декартовой системе координат. А если это так, то вы можете откладывать на оси ординат величины в любых размерных единицах (будь то градусы, радианы, килограммы, кулверстукасы или что-то еще).

Если же речь идет о графике в полярной системе координат, то терминология абсцисса/ордината неверна в принципе. Нужно говорить о радиусе и угле. При этом, угол откладывается в радианах. Собственно, только в этом случае имеет смысл переводить значения углов из градусов в радианы.